# Hide html dropdownlist from the jquery dialog on specific rows of GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, gridview

I'm new to Jquery, any help would be appreciated for below issue that m facing.
I have a GridView, on click of a row from Gridview(lnkView) a Jquery dialog(div:#dialog) opens which contains html dropdown(#projectcode) element.I want to hide the dropdown on click of certain rows.How to do that? 
Code below: HTML

`<script type="text/javascript">$("[id*=lnkView]").live("click", function () {`

```
        var datesent = $(this).next().text();

        var subject = $(this).text();
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("#body").html($(".body", row).html());

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            width: 700,
            title: subject,
            buttons: [{
                id: "ok", text: "Ok",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }]
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmails" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MessageNumber" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDateSent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateSent") %>' />
                    <span class="body" style="display: none">
                        <%# Eval("Body") %></span>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none" runat="server">
        <span id="body"></span>
        <select id="projectcode" runat="server">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <option value="00111">Fedex - 001</option>
            <option value="00112">UPS - 002</option>
        </select>

        <br />
    </div>`
```

And below is the c# code

```
for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Email email = new Email()
            {
                MessageNumber = i,
                Subject = message.Headers.Subject,
                DateSent = message.Headers.DateSent,
                GUID = pop3Client.GetMessageUid(i),
            };

           SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select GUID from Sample where        GUID = '" + email.GUID + "' ", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                if (email.GUID == dr.GetString(0))
                {
                    //The below condition what I want to achieve for a specific row which has email.GUID == dr.GetString()-- GUID
                    //projectcode.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
                   // projectcode.Visible = false;


                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want an onclick function so when you click on a row in your gridview it will dropdown with information. When you click on it again you want it to hide.

so lets say this is one row in your gridview with aria-expanded set to true.

```
 <tr class="toggle-display" aria-expanded="true">
 <td>@information.Stuff</td>
 </tr>
```

and here you have the message that will show in your dropdown.

```
 <tr class="display-message">
        <span>Information:</span> @information.Things
 </tr>
```

The jquery would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-display', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).next('.display-message').hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).next('.display-message').removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded', "false");
    } else {
        $(this).next('.display-message').addClass('expanded', 1000);
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded', "true");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, just to make it more clear what I want is when my GridView loads on PageLoad I have to check if for a selected row their exist a data in table or not.If a record match is found for a particular row then i want to disable the dropdown for that row ONLY.I have a click event on the linkButton of every row.